# Activity de Log para sincronização capturando dados de tarefa rodando em background

Tags: java, android, thread

Desenvolvo um aplicativo em Cordova, que faz sincronia com um banco de dados online, a parte de sincronia esta toda em Java.(Contexto do app)

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma tela de "Log" para a sincronia da qual será mostrada para o usuário quantos registros foram sincronizados com sucesso, quantos com erro e os respectivos erros.

Através de pesquisas cheguei a conclusão que devo usar uma Thread para ficar "ouvindo" a sincronização.

A pergunta é a seguinte: Vi na documentação que AsyncTask deve ser usada para tarefas da ordem de poucos segundos de execução e para tarefas mais demoradas usar Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor e FutureTask. A sincronização costuma demorar ate horas na primeira sincronização. Devo realmente usar a segunda opção? Se sim alguem tem um tutorial bom que me mostre como faze-la pois o que já pesquisei não consigo aplicar para meu problema.

Por que o AsyncTask não pode ser usado para tarefas demoradas?

Answer (score 0):

As AsyncTasks, por padrão, [trabalham como uma fila compartilhada](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#order-of-execution). Todas as tarefas são executadas de forma serial, uma de cada vez, por uma thread em background.

Isso quer dizer que **se você tiver uma tarefa que demore muito para terminar, outras tarefas que forem eventualmente enfileiradas terão que ficar esperando para serem executadas**.

Se você tiver a garantia que outras tarefas não serão enfileiradas enquando sua sincronização acontece, ou que esses enfileiramentos não trarão problemas, pode usar sem problemas.

Caso contrário, é possível fazer com que a AsyncTask trabalhe de forma paralela. Basta executá-la com o método `executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[])`, passando um `Executor` diferente do padrão. A AsyncTask já oferece o `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`, ou você pode criar o seu.

Note que isso pode trazer [bugs de paralelismo devido à sequência de execução indefinida](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...))

---

Quanto a um exemplo de utilização de um `Executor` ou `ThreadPoolExecutor`
você pode [consultar o source da própria AsyncTask](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#213), já que ela também usa este mecanismo para executar suas tarefas.